# How to move updates from Google Play to another server

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, android-keystore

Our users have many Android devices with the same google account.
Updating our application is a nightmare for users.
They have to log in to Google Play and enter a confirmation SMS
which is sent to the only common phone.

The new app will have another package ID, since direct update is prohibited.
No problem to get data from the original app.

The problem is to share key pair and custom SSL certificate
which the original app received from our server after CSR request.

So, is it possible to export the key pair and SSL certificate to another app signed with the same key?

Thank you!

I could not find an answer on the internet.

Comment: If an app is installed via Google Play Store or not has nothing to do with the procedure required to update it. If the update process is complicated then it is this way because the app developer has designed it that way.